# Isomorphism of K-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, extension-field

Let $k[x]$ be a polynomial ring and $I$ an ideal (resp. graded). If $k\subset K$ is a field extension, then prove that there is a natural (resp. graded) isomorphism of $K$-algebras: $$K[x]/IK[x]\cong k[x]/I\otimes_{k}K.$$

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of the various isomorphism theorems for algebras, or the universal properties of polynomial algebras and tensor products?

Comment: Have you tried just writing down the obvious maps between those algebras?

Comment: you can try to show that they are both left adjoints of the restriction of scalars. This gives you both the isomorphism and naturality.

Comment: alternatively, look at the bilinear map $\phi: k[x]/I\times K\rightarrow K[X]/IK[X]$ sending $(k,x)\mapsto kx$. This induces a linear map $\psi: K\otimes_k k[x]/I$ by the UMP of the tensor product. Show that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I tried the following way: We have the exact sequence $0\longrightarrow I\longrightarrow k[x]\longrightarrow k[x]/I\longrightarrow 0.$ Tensoring we get the exact sequence $I\otimes_{k}K\longrightarrow k[x]\otimes_{k}K\longrightarrow k[x]/I\otimes_{k}K\longrightarrow 0.$
Thus, $k[x]/I\otimes_{k}K\cong k[x]\otimes_{k}K/ker(π⊗1)$. But, by exactness $ker(π⊗1)=im(i⊗1)$. It's trivial that $k[x]\otimes_{k}K\cong K[x]$ and that when we consider this isomorphism we find that $im(i⊗1)=I$.

Comment: Is it alright? and what about the graded case?

Comment: @KReiser Is it alright? and what about the graded case?

Comment: @user118827 that works too (with $im(i\otimes 1)=IK[x]$).